# Compute for average of grades in R (RStudio)

Tags: r

csv excel file (CLASS RECORD.csv) imported to RStudio

[image]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By0EBRkKuYC3bUViM2ZPRElpSEE

by using a variable it becomes:

```
> classrecord=(CLASS.RECORD)
> classrecord
         V1 V2 V3 V4 V5   V6      V7
1     Names Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Exam Project
2      ABLE 35 35 30 15   78      80
3   ALVAREZ 30 36 30 15   86      90
4 CARBAJOSA 50 28 30 18   88      90
5      KHAW 30 36 30 15   70      85
6  TAGUIBAO 50 45 30 18   92      95
7     TILOG 28 32 30 10   63      80
8  VIRTUCIO 26 30 30 15   72      80
```

how do I go about and compute for a term grade column? id like to add the other all up to 100% for that term grade: 40 % of average of Q1+Q1+Q3+Q4 (total 150), 40% of the Exam (total 100), and 20% of the project (total 100).

im told that you have to add a data frame and compute in order to create a new column (i apologize for just giving a few lines of code, we were given this task without prior knowledge of R)

i created: CLASS.RECORD$Term_Grade <- (Term_Grade = 0)

```
UPDATE: classrecord <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE) (find the excel file)
        classrecord$Term_Grade <- ((classrecord$Q1 + classrecord$Q2 + classrecord$Q3 + classrecord$Q4)/150*50+50 *0.4 + classrecord$Exam*0.4+classrecord$Project*0.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat <- read.csv('CLASS RECORD.csv', header = TRUE)
dat$Grade <- (0.4 * (dat$Q1 + dat$Q2 + dat$Q3 + dat$Q4)) + (0.4 * dat$Exam) + (0.2 * dat$Project)
```

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(classrecord$V2, classrecord$V3) :
  ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(classrecord$V2 + classrecord$V3, classrecord$V4) :
  ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(classrecord$V2 + classrecord$V3 + classrecord$V4,  :
  ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(0.4, classrecord$V6) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(0.2, classrecord$V7) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: How did you read the data? If you did it the right way it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i apologize but when trying to get the CLASS RECORD.csv it says: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'CLASS RECORD.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: Your file has to be in the same folder as your R project. Or provide path to it.

Comment: dat <- read.csv(file.choose()) is this the right code? how do i go to the directory of my .csv file?

Comment: `dat <- read.csv(file.choose())` - yes you can do that. Find your file and copy paste it to desktop, than you will find it easily :)

Comment: yes haha the .csv was found, however when i used the 2nd line of code, the Grades say NA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129870/discussion-between-kipras-kancys-and-ragnalugria).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some verbose code that will create a new column:

```
class.record <- data.frame(
                    Names = c('Chris','John','Bob'),
                    Q1 = c(35,30,50),
                    Q2 = c(35,36,28),
                    Q3 = c(30,30,30),
                    Q4 = c(15,15,18),
                    Exam = c(76,86,88),
                    Project = c(80,90,90)
                    )

q <- ((class.record$Q1+class.record$Q2+class.record$Q3+class.record$Q4)/150)*.4
e <- class.record$Exam/100*.4
p <- class.record$Project/100*.2
class.record$term_grade <- q+e+p
print(class.record)
```

Your data includes headers, but it is not loaded correctly. Can you post the code you used to load the data? It is probably something like `CLASS.RECORD <- read.csv("/path/to/data.csv")` You need to add `header=TRUE` to that statement.

Comment: i added CLASS.RECORD$Term_Grade <- (Term_Grade = 0)